# AJAX Laravel Update Database

Tags: ajax, laravel

My issue is that I'm doing a simple AJAX Post to update a database record, but I'm not getting any error and it's still not updating the record. What am I overlooking?

Thanks!

JS:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {
            'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        }
}); 

if ($('.abc-status').css('display') == 'block')
{
    abc.api({method: 'user'}, function(error, user) {

        var userId = $('.oath_id').text();  
        var username = user.display_name;
        console.log(username);
        $.ajax({

            type: "POST",
            url: "oauth_authorization/abc/"+username,
            data: {abc_username: username},
            error: function(data){
                console.log(data);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Controller:

```
public function postabcOAuth(Request $request, $username)
{
    Auth::user()->update([
        'abc_username' => $username,
    ]); 
}
```

Route:

```
Route::post('/oauth_authorization/abc/{username}', [
    'uses' => '\abc\Http\Controllers\OAuthController@postAbcOAuth',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the following in the Controller, I was able to get it to work.

```
public function postAbcOAuth(Request $request, $username)

{
    DB::table('users')
        ->where('id',Auth::user()->id)
        ->update(['abc_username' => $username]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change the post method in route path and also in ajax function